# Custom Vlookup for Google App Scritp

Tags: vba, google-apps-script

i have a ms excel file with vba code and it works smoothly , but i need to upload it on google with google app scrpit . how can i convert my vba code into Google Script? here my code:

Function MYVLOOKUP(pValue As String, pWorkRng As Range, pIndex As Long)
'Update 20150310
Dim rng As Range
Dim xResult As String

xResult = ""
For Each rng In pWorkRng
    If rng = pValue And rng.Offset(0, -1).Value = "Mathematics" Then
        xResult = xResult & " " & rng.Offset(0, pIndex - 1)

```
ElseIf rng = pValue And rng.Offset(0, -1).Value = "English" Then
    xResult = xResult & " " & rng.Offset(0, pIndex - 1)

    ElseIf rng = pValue And rng.Offset(0, -1).Value = "Science" Then
    xResult = xResult & " " & rng.Offset(0, pIndex - 1)

    ElseIf rng = pValue And rng.Offset(0, -1).Value = "Filipino" Then
    xResult = xResult & " " & rng.Offset(0, pIndex - 1)

    ElseIf rng = pValue And rng.Offset(0, -1).Value = "Araling Panlipunan" Then
    xResult = xResult & " " & rng.Offset(0, pIndex - 1)

    ElseIf rng = pValue And rng.Offset(0, -1).Value = "MAPEH" Then
    xResult = xResult & " " & rng.Offset(0, pIndex - 1)

    ElseIf rng = pValue And rng.Offset(0, -1).Value = "TLE" Then
    xResult = xResult & " " & rng.Offset(0, pIndex - 1)

    ElseIf rng = pValue And rng.Offset(0, -1).Value = "Values Education" Then
    xResult = xResult & " " & rng.Offset(0, pIndex - 1)
End If
```

Next
MYVLOOKUP = xResult
End Function

Comment: learn Javascript and Apps Script and convert your method.

Comment: can you explain in words?